# bash: PROMPT_COMMAND does not execute multiple commands, single command works

Tags: bash, shell

In ~/.bashrc
Say I have a function say,

```
function my_function {  
echo "Test:I am in myfunc"  
}
```

- If I do alone
  `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"'`
  then work fine.
- If I do
  `export PROMPT_COMMAND="my_function;$PROMPT_COMMAND"`
  then it works fine.
- But if I do
  `export PROMPT_COMMAND="'echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"';my_function;$PROMPT_COMMAND"`
  Then it does not set the tab name or call my_function.
  Plz help ..

Comment: Learn how to use [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, yeah sometimes those nested single/double quotes can get be difficult.  Why don't you try moving the first command (setting the tab name to the current directory), into `my_function`.  So try putting this into your ~/.bashrc:

```
function my_function {
    echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"
    echo "Test:I am in myfunc"
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND="my_function;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: I mean, if I am in directory name /dir1/gir2/dir3/ so my tab title will become dir3. (  Want my_function should also get call after this done )

Comment: @ypp Ah!  I see, ok well I edited my answer.  I believe it does what you want.  Give it a shot, but let me know if I'm not fully understanding something.